# Determining a possible metric for level of 'cute'

Tags: algorithm

First, I'm not sure if this is a valid question for SO, but I was just wondering for a general direction I should look.

There's a handful of algorithms out there that can determine (human) facial attractiveness using various algorithms based on certain criteria that've been proven to be universal attractive.

I was wondering about giving a metric or mark for the 'cuteness' of a picture. Now this is a really really subjective/hard question. Is this possible from an algorithm perceptive? Using things like the colors present in the image, the quality of the image, etc. ?

Comment: You mean generally like puppies and teddy bears? Or cute as a type of facial beauty? (I don't know the answer either way, just prodding.)

Comment: I think more in the directions of puppies. What makes one picture of a puppy more appealing or 'cute' than another (for more people)?

Comment: Look into the differences between precocial and altricial faces. That's a start. Precocial "cute" faces share certain characterists, such as the clustering of features, esp. relative to the spatial layout of adult features.

Answer (score 5):

I would combine two metrics: **color lightness** and **presence of sharp curves**. Anything more complex, like detecting faces and measuring their eye and head size will quickly fail for non-human subjects. For example:

[image: Cute Cthulhu]

The mean color is very light and there are few pointy tips, while the face and body are hard to recognize.

For the color you could just take the mean or median value and check if it's below a threshold, or run a more complex function on the image histogram.

I don't know if there are "sharpness detection" algorithms, but you could start with an edge detection one and try to detect the pointy bits there:

[image: Edge detection algorithm example]

Real fur and hair may give you trouble on the second metric, so distinguishing between drawings and images could help.

Answer (score 3):

It's going to be pretty hard because the algorithm will not only have to detect things commonly associated with cuteness, like kittens, puppies and babies, but also interpret the context of what is being pictured.

For example it's a common knowledge that a sleeping baby is over twice as cute as a non sleeping one which is roughly just as cute as a pair of puppies, depending on the breed. At the same time the puppies playing are about 70% cuter than puppies fighting and 40% cuter than puppies eating most kinds of food, depending on the camera angle and lighting.

Not only that, but the cuteness of a given picture can come from understanding a deeper meaning behind it. For example an old dog sitting on a stone is not nearly as cute as the same dog sitting on his dead master's grave or a little girl with a flower can be more or less cute depending on who is she giving the flower to, her expression etc.

Unlike beauty, which can be somewhat quantified, cuteness doesn't have much to do with physical features.

Comment: I can only lift my hat to this display of immense expertism on the subject of cute.

Comment: There are statistics for cuteness? Is the some official source you got them or...?

Comment: @Jerry: I think the results Marian is referring to were published by the Association of Cute in 2008